# Shell Script mkdir if not and mv files to each day

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I need to check in a dir that have 150.000 zip files with this kind of format :

```
log_from_2012_08_14-11:57:12_To_2012_08_14-13:57:12.zip
log_from_2012_08_14-13:57:12_To_2012_08_14-15:57:12.zip
log_from_2012_08_14-15:57:12_To_2012_08_14-17:57:12.zip
```

if there is a dir with the name equals to the day of the file :

```
2012_08_14
```

then move all files that exist from that From_2012_08_14 to that dir, if not create it

> ( mkdir date +%Y_%M_%D )

and then check for each day since august until today november , every file from a day that doenst have is own dir create it and move it there.

Comment: So if a file covers `2012_08-14-23:57:12_To_2012_08_15-01:57:12`, it goes in the folder for the 'from' date, not the 'to' date?

Comment: 150,000 files; 1 file every two hours; that's a lot of days (12,500 days or so, or 30+ years).  What other file name formats do you have?

Answer (score 1):

```
cd /relevant/log/directory

# Create the necessary sub-directories
ls *from_????_??_??-??:??:??_To_????_??_??-??:??:??.zip |
sed 's/.*from_\([0-9]\{4\}_[0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9]\).*/\1/' |
sort -u |
xargs mkdir -p

# Move the files into the sub-directories
ls *from_????_??_??-??:??:??_To_????_??_??-??:??:??.zip |
sed 's/.*from_\([0-9]\{4\}_[0-9][0-9]_[0-9][0-9]\).*/mv & \1;/' |
sh -x
```

The `-x` is optional, but shows you what is happening while it is happening.  I'm assuming that none of your file names contain spaces or newlines.  I'm also assuming there aren't files with alphanumerics where the `?` in the shell patterns is expected to match digits.  You can expand each `?` to `[0-9]` if you have to be utterly paranoid, or revise the `sed` scripts to discard names that don't match, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty Bash solution

```
for file in log_from*.zip; do
    dirname=${file#log_from_}
    dirname=${dirname%%-*}
    [ ! -d "$dirname" ] && mkdir "$dirname"
    mv "$file" "$dirname"
done
```

Comment: hmmm i get a error of cannot mv "log_from*.zip" to a subdirectory of itstel,